# Como listar consulta BD

Tags: php, html, mysql, html5, banco-de-dados

Boa noite!
Como faço para listar uma consulta no banco de dados?
Tenho um banco onde armazena Cantores e suas músicas...
Queria listar estilo spotify, listando numeralmente conforme a quantidade de conteúdo no banco.
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Vejo meu exemplo no db:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Código:

```
<?php
    $mysqli = new mysqli("host", "user", "senha", "db");

    if (mysqli_connect_errno()) {
        printf("Connect failed: %s\n", mysqli_connect_error());
        exit();
    }

    $count = 1;

    if ($sth = $mysqli->query("SELECT * FROM artistas")){
        while ($row = $sth->fetch_assoc()){
            echo $count . " - " . $row['cantor'] . "<br>";
            $count++;
        }
    }
```

Resultado:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: Deu certo amigo! Muito obrigado...

Comment: @VictorFreitas fico feliz que funcionou, mas peço que marque a resposta como aceita para que outros que tiverem o msm problema possam resolver tb